# jQuery Audio Navigation

Tags: jquery, audio, navigation

I want to create a Audio Navigation bar using jQuery and HTML5, however it doesn't work.

Anybody who can help!

```
<nav class="wrapper-nav">
  <ul class="mianMenu">
    <li class="first"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Grooming</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    <audio id="myaudio" src="dogbark.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="myaudio2" src="miaow.mp3"></audio>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
$("li").hover(function(){$("#myaudio").play()}
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because `$("#myaudio")` returns a jquery object and the jquery object do not have a play method. 
For the play method to work you have to give it a native dom element.
so $("#myaudio")[0] will work.

here is a working example:

```js
$(function() {
    $('li').hover(function() {
        if ($("#myaudio")[0].paused == false) {
            $("#myaudio")[0].pause();
        } else {
            $("#myaudio")[0].play();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="wrapper-nav">
    <ul class="mianMenu">
        <li class="first"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Grooming</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
        <audio id="myaudio" src="audio.mp3"></audio>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Note: this example is just for demonstration purpose, you should store your selectors `$("#myaudio")[0]` in a variable in production